# Powershell split string - one works and one doesn't. Why?

Tags: powershell, split

I wrote this one without the variable while figuring out how to go about doing what I needed:

```
#Variables
$replace='2.55'
$filepath= 'C:\folder\path\bond.out'
#go straight to the line I want to change something in
$data = Get-Content $filepath | select -skip 38 -first 1
#split it all, find the other variable and overwrite it
$split=$data.split("{|}")
$split[3]=$replace
#put it all back again
$join = $split -join "|"
write-output $join
```

This works perfectly.

I then changed the "$data" line to select the variable instead:

```
#Variables
$replace='2.55'
$filepath= 'C:\folder\path\bond.out'
#find the variable
$data = Get-Content $filepath | select-string $bond
#split it all, find the other variable and overwrite it
$split=$data.split("{|}")
$split[3]=$replace
#put it all back again
$join = $split -join "|"
write-output $join
```

Now I get the below error:

[image]

I understand the second error block is because the first error block occurred, but don't understand why it now doesn't work at all?

Comment: I just figured out why! Because the variable $bond finds a word but does not collect the whole line. Would anyone know how to do that by any chance?

Comment: I'd be surprised if it isn't a duplicate. The basic issue is the output from `Select-String` is a MatchInfo object and not a generic string type object. The regular "select" command used in the first script example is an alias for `Select-Object`.

Comment: You may want to try using `Where-Object { $_ -match $bond }` instead of `Select-String $bond`. Select-String returns MatchInfo objects that require more work to pull results out of.

Comment: @mike z: Legend, that was it. I had a much more long winded solution in place but this is way cleaner. Thank you so much! If you put it in as an answer, I will give you the green tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, `Select-String` outputs a MatchInfo, not a String.  Also, you don't need `Get-Content` with `Select-String`.  It does that for you already.

Try this:

```
$data = Select-String -Path $filepath -Pattern $bond | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
```